# Optimize python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm developing a Python script to process a text file, which reads file line by line, each line will create a new file on S3 bucket. I need to make it faster.

So the slow part is putting new file to S3 bucket. I have already used multiprocessing, but it is still too slow. Can someone help me optimize this script please?

```
def write_to_s3(file_name, data):
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket='bucket_name',
                                    Body=data,
                                    Key=file_name)

def process_line(line):
   # do something here
   write_to_s3(file_name, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_pool = Pool(processes=inp_process_number)

    with open(inp_filename, 'r') as source_file:
        next(
             process_pool
                    .imap(process_line, source_file, inp_line_per_process)
            )
        process_pool.close()
        process_pool.join()
```

Comment: How have you determined that the slowest part is creating the new file in S3? Are they definitely running in parallel?

Comment: It's not clear if the overall run time of your process is slow or you just want the s3 write to be faster??? You can use faster ec2 instances, or ones with larger CPU counts, or invoke the process_line function as a lambda function (memory and time dependencies may hinder this). If lambda works you can have quite a  bit of parallel processing going for you.

Comment: Lambda has time and memory limit so processing a large file is impossible.

Comment: Yes the slowest part is creating new file in S3 for sure. And they are not running in parrallel.